# Google Chrome has taken over all HTML handling... 

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, file-extension

It's really getting on my nerves, but Google Chrome has taken over all HTML handling.

For example, when you open Spotify... it runs C:/Users//AppData/Local/Spotify/flashdetect.html, but now that page is acctually opened in chrome as a new window.

This also is the case for my Asus GamerOSD application that is located in tray. If I try to open settings Chrome takes over and opens C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/ASUS/GamerOSD/Skin/GamerOSD.html instead of the application doing it... :(

Anyone know this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the .htm and .html classes in the registry. Chrome has a habit of changing these to ChromeHTML

1. Open Regedit
2. Find the key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html
3. Right click the (Default) value for the .html key and select Modify...
4. Change the value from "ChromeHTML" to "htmlfile"

Do this for .htm as well.

Comment: Did not help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what web browser you want to be the default, but you can do this from within that browser.

If you have set the "check for default browser" option in your preferred browser then the next time you open it it should ask you if you want to set it to be the default again. Say "yes" and you're good to go.

If you haven't enabled that option then you'll need to manually make it the default again:

**For IE8**

- Open the browser.
- Select **Tools > Internet Options...** then the **Programs** tab.
- In the "Default web browser" section click on the "Make Default" button.

IE is now your default browser.

**For Firefox**

- Open the browser
- Select **Tools > Options...** then the **Advanced** panel and **General** tab.
- Click on the "Check Now" button in the bottom left of the dialog.

[Screen shots and full details](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/How%20to%20make%20Firefox%20the%20default%20browser)

Firefox is now your default browser.

Other browsers have similar options